# Can't put ' / ' after the letter ' l ' on terminal, makes weird symbol

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Every time I try to write my directory local or any word ending with an 'l' and then press the '/' symbol it seems to make another symbol, how can i deactivate that function? 
*** Gif attached on script to illustrate ***

```html
<iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/xT0GqG50jpqlIOXp2o" width="480" height="352" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/command-terminal-xT0GqG50jpqlIOXp2o">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

Comment: This looks like some automation interprets your typing. There a lot of them in OSX, and depending on your locale. One of them is located in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text, you may also have some accessibility activated that let users type combinations to obtains specials chars, etc.

Comment: To add to @Jean-BaptisteYunès's comment : there are softwares like autohotkey, which can also be used to correct typos (e.g. `teh` becomes `the`) or they can also be used for shorthand ( e.g. `(c)` becomes `©`) These watch your typing & can produce different keystrokes to the system than what you typed. (Autohotkey is a windows software, but as previous comment said, there are similar s/w on OSX also)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This seems to only happen inside the terminal, if I do it on normal text window it stays the letter and the slash ' l/ '.

Comment: @anishsane how can I deactivate this functions, where is the panel for it?

Comment: I don't know. I am not an OSX user...